# Java Trinomial Solver/Factorer sometimes giving wrong answers

Tags: java, android

I'm new to both Java and Android developing, and I decided to try making an app that solves trinomials. So far it only works for some trinomials, but not all, and I can't figure out why.

For instance, if I enter `1x^2 + 5x + 6` I get the correct answers (-3, and -2).

But if I enter `1x^2 - 1x - 6` I get two long decimal answers when I should get 3 and -2.

It does solve `1x^2 - 21a + 104` correctly though, which makes me think the problem isn't with handling negatives.

I tried translating the code to C++ (since I'm more familiar with it) and that program gave the correct answers for all trinomials. So I'm thinking the issue is that I'm just bad at java.

My code:

```
package com.example.todd.factortrinomials;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {

        //  declare variables
        EditText aNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aBox);
        EditText bNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bBox);
        EditText cNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cBox);
        EditText aSign = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box1);
        EditText bSign = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box2);
        EditText cSign = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box3);

        TextView ans1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x1Box);
        TextView ans2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x2Box);

        //  input
        int a = Integer.parseInt(aNum.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(bNum.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(cNum.getText().toString());
        String a1 = (aSign.getText().toString());
        String b1 = (bSign.getText().toString());
        String c1 = (cSign.getText().toString());


        //  process solution
        if (a1 == "-") a = -1 * a;
        if (b1 == "-") b = -1 * b;
        if (c1 == "-") c = -1 * c;

        double temp1 = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
        if (temp1 >= 0) temp1 = Math.sqrt(temp1);
        else {temp1 = Math.sqrt(-1*temp1); temp1 = -1 * temp1;}
        double x1 = (-b + temp1) / (2*a);
        double x2 = (-b - temp1) / (2*a);


        //output
        ans1.setText(Double.toString(x1));
        ans2.setText(Double.toString(x2));
    }
}
```

Other info: The signs (plus or minus) for A, B, and C are read separately as strings because the text fields for A, B, and C didn't want to accept negative numbers for some reason. It sounds sloppy, but it works. I'm 90% sure the error is in the logic though. Maybe when I assigned the three String variables?

I can give the `activity_main.xml` code if anyone wants to test it on their own. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I tried a few more equations and it *looks* like I only get the wrong answer if temp1 is negative. Meaning the way I handle it when I find temp1's square root might be skewing the answer. I'm not sure how to fix it if that is the problem though.

Comment: "I get two long decimal answers" What exactly do you get?

Comment: "What exactly do you get?" I got x1 = -2.8979157616 and x2 = 1.8979157616

Comment: Weird how both of those numbers end in the same digits.

Comment: In Java, `==` doesn't do what you want for strings.  Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I fixed that. It didn't seem to have an impact on the main problem though. I have a feeling the mistake is somewhere under `if (temp1 >= 0) temp1 = Math.sqrt(temp1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I made aBox, bBox, and cBox each accept number, signed number, and decimal number types. This got rid of my need for the +/- strings. It now works for all trinomials that don't have imaginary answers. I also removed this portion:

```
if (temp1 >= 0) temp1 = Math.sqrt(temp1);
else {temp1 = Math.sqrt(-1*temp1); temp1 = -1 * temp1;}
```

And replaced it with `temp1 = Math.sqrt(temp1);`, as what I had did absolutely nothing except give a wrong answer if the trinomial entered returns an imaginary answer, which it currently does anyways.